# R regex expressions in tidyr and dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a file composed of thousands of lines of this type:

```
1   number  entry   size1   size2   value   size5   value2  my_id1k "AJKJjsdfe76r55"; my_label “1900”; my_idk2 "49354ytu866"; you_digit "some"; my_copy “jkl”;
1   number  entry   size3   size4   value   size6   value2  my_id1k "xyz804"; my_id2k “FI71"; my_id3k “Sk9000”; my_id4k “ldv”;
```

I would like to find a way to extract what's enclosed within the `my_id1k` and `my_id2k` entries (without the double quotes), as well as extract some of the other columns (my code is provided below).

I’d like to use the `separate()` and `select()` functions in the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages for this purpose because they're very fast (and I'm concerned about performance), so I’ve been studying: http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/tidyr/man/separate.html

However, I’m not sure how to specify the `into` and `sep` options in this kind of heterogeneous case (where my last column has varying length) in order to get my desired output. I clearly have some lines that have more info than others, so I’m wondering how I could write some high-performance `tidyr` and `dplyr` code that extracts the desired entries as quickly as possible.

Here's my work so far:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(data.table)
> x <- fread("myfile_MWE.txt")
> x
   V1     V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7     V8                                                                                                 V9
1:  1 number entry size1 size2 value size5 value2 my_id1k "AJKJjsdfe76r55"; my_label “1900”; my_idk2 "49354ytu866"; you_digit "some"; my_copy “jkl”;
2:  1 number entry size3 size4 value size6 value2                                 my_id1k "xyz804"; my_id2k “FI71"; my_id3k “Sk9000”; my_id4k “ldv”;
> y <- separate(x, V9, into = paste("V", 1:15, sep = "_"))
> y
   V1     V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7     V8 V_1  V_2            V_3 V_4   V_5  V_6 V_7  V_8         V_9 V_10  V_11 V_12 V_13 V_14 V_15
1:  1 number entry size1 size2 value size5 value2  my id1k AJKJjsdfe76r55  my label 1900  my idk2 49354ytu866  you digit some   my copy  jkl
2:  1 number entry size3 size4 value size6 value2  my id1k         xyz804  my  id2k FI71  my id3k      Sk9000   my  id4k  ldv        NA   NA
```

Clearly, due to the differing length of the last column (`V9`), some entries show up as `NA`, and I can't manage to successfully extract what's enclosed within the `my_id1k` and `my_id2k` entries:

```
> a <- select(y, V1, V7, V_3, V_9)
> a
   V1    V7            V_3         V_9
1:  1 size5 AJKJjsdfe76r55 49354ytu866
2:  1 size6         xyz804      Sk9000
> b <- select(y, V1, V7, V_3, V_6)
> b
   V1    V7            V_3  V_6
1:  1 size5 AJKJjsdfe76r55 1900
2:  1 size6         xyz804 FI71
```

So clearly, in one case I need `V_9` and in the other case I need `V_6`.  My desired output would be:

```
1 size5 AJKJjsdfe76r55 49354ytu866
1 size6         xyz804 FI71
```

Is there anyway that I can specify the usage of `V_9` and `V_6` in a conditional manner so that the my code is smart enough to recognize that I want to pull down what's enclosed within the `my_id1k` and `my_id2k` entries, e.g., via regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::extract` is a better option than `separate` or `spread`, as there's a lot of gunk you don't care about.

```
extract(df, V9, c('my_id1k', 'my_id2k'), 'my_id1k .(\\S+).;.*my_id(?:2k|k2) .(\\S+).;')
#   V1     V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7     V8        my_id1k     my_id2k
# 1  1 number entry size1 size2 value size5 value2 AJKJjsdfe76r55 49354ytu866
# 2  1 number entry size3 size4 value size6 value2         xyz804        FI71
```

Note this assumes `my_id2k` and `my_idk2` are the same, as you seem to assume as much in the question; `my_id1k` doesn't vary, so the regex doesn't either. It also assumes `my_id1k` comes before `my_id2k`. Be aware of the possibilities when extending it to new data, and adjust the regex accordingly.

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "number", class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "entry", class = "factor"), 
    V4 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("size1", "size3"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("size2", "size4"), class = "factor"), 
    V6 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "value", class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("size5", "size6"), class = "factor"), 
    V8 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "value2", class = "factor"), 
    V9 = c("my_id1k \"AJKJjsdfe76r55\"; my_label “1900”; my_idk2 \"49354ytu866\"; you_digit \"some\"; my_copy “jkl”;", 
    "my_id1k \"xyz804\"; my_id2k “FI71\"; my_id3k “Sk9000”; my_id4k “ldv”;"
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8", "V9"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Neat regex.  And, indeed, thank you for pointing out the `extract()` function, wasn't familiar with that one! +1!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the data I used:

```
data = structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L), V2 = c("number", "number"), V3 = c("entry", 
"entry"), V4 = c("size1", "size3"), V5 = c("size2", "size4"), 
    V6 = c("value", "value"), V7 = c("size5", "size6"), V8 = c("value2", 
    "value2"), V9 = c("my_id1k \"AJKJjsdfe76r55\"; my_label “1900”; my_idk2 \"49354ytu866\"; you_digit \"some\"; my_copy “jkl”;", 
    "my_id1k \"xyz804\"; my_id2k “FI71\"; my_id3k “Sk9000”; my_id4k “ldv”;"
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", 
"V8", "V9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

And here's the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

result = 
  data %>%
  group_by(V9) %>%
  do(.$V9 %>%
       first %>%
       stri_replace_all_fixed("; ", "\n") %>%
       read.table(text = ., stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%
  spread(V1, V2) %>%
  left_join(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, very much like your alternative solution, especially the usage of the `stringi` library. +1!

Comment: Good use of `do`.  Plus one.